# Unable to get correct ETA using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I am collecting ETA for few locations for some project work. I get different time duration during different point of time, but there is one case which returns same results

Origin: Acres Club, 411-B, Hemu Kalani Marg, Sindhi Society, Chembur, Mumbai, Maharashtra
Destination: Chhatrapati Shivaji Terminus, Chhatrapati Shivaji Terminus Area, Mumbai, Maharashtra
This always returns `1702` seconds.

Below is the API call I am making:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Acres%20Club,%20411-B,%20Hemu%20Kalani%20Marg,%20Sindhi%20Society,%20Chembur,%20Mumbai,%20Maharashtra&destinations=Chhatrapati%20Shivaji%20Terminus,%20Chhatrapati%20Shivaji%20Terminus%20Area,%20Mumbai,%20Maharashtra&key=

Let me know if I am missing anything. Thanks in Aadvance.

Comment: Why do you believe the number should change at different times? (It isn't a very long trip)

Comment: @geocodezip Even with a short distance, this route should show difference output. You are asking reason on why number should change when you travel from point A to point B during peak time v/s mid-night with significantly different traffic conditions. 

In addition to this, Google maps are showing different time but its API is not.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly you are interested in getting a duration taking into account current traffic conditions. Please note that duration with traffic conditions requires a departure time to be specified in your request.

Have a look at the documentation that reads:

> **departure_time** — The desired time of departure. You can specify the time as an integer in seconds since midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC. Alternatively, you can specify a value of now, which sets the departure time to the current time (correct to the nearest second).
>
> For requests where the travel mode is driving: You can specify the departure_time to receive a route and trip duration (response field: duration_in_traffic) that take traffic conditions into account. This option is only available if the request contains a valid API key, or a valid Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID and signature. The departure_time must be set to the current time or some time in the future. It cannot be in the past.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#DistanceMatrixRequests

I would suggest changing you request to

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Acres%20Club%2C%20411-B%2C%20Hemu%20Kalani%20Marg%2C%20Sindhi%20Society%2C%20Chembur%2C%20Mumbai%2C%20Maharashtra&destinations=Chhatrapati%20Shivaji%20Terminus%2C%20Chhatrapati%20Shivaji%20Terminus%20Area%2C%20Mumbai&departure_time=now&traffic_model=best_guess&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

In this case you will see something similar to

```
"rows":[
{
  "elements":[
    {
      "distance":{
        "text":"16.2 km",
        "value":16206
      },
      "duration":{
        "text":"28 mins",
        "value":1702
      },
      "duration_in_traffic":{
        "text":"45 mins",
        "value":2715
      },
      "status":"OK"
    }
  ]
}
],
```

in your response. Where `duration_in_traffic` shows duration taking into account current traffic conditions and `duration` is a typical average duration.

Hope this helps!

Comment: We now have Routes API